# Join 3 table in peewee

Tags: python, peewee

I want to be able to join multiple tables in peewee. the scenario is a little difficult for me to figure out how to get it to work with peewee.
I have the following tables:
user,product,images

this is my models:

```
class user(BaseModel):
    id = AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = CharField()
    password = CharField()

class product(BaseModel):
    id = AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_user = ForeignKeyField(user)
    product_name = CharField()
    product_price = IntegerField()
    product_description = TextField()

class images(BaseModel):
    id = AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_product = ForeignKeyField(barang)
    image_name = TextField()
```

i want the output like this product.id,user.username,product.product_name,product.price,product.product_description,images.image_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query = (Product
         .select(Product, User, Image)
         .join_from(Product, User)
         .join_from(Product, Image))
for product in query:
    print(product.product_name)
    print(product.id_user.username)
    print(product.images.image_name)
```

This is all documented very thoroughly here: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html

Please read the docs.